# Checking Pangram in Python

Tags: python, pangram

I am trying to use .pop to check the pangram and have the following code but get the error "'str' object has no attribute 'pop'". I am new to programming. Please help.

```
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    for x in str1:
        if x in alphabet:
            alphabet.pop[0]
        else:
            pass
    return len(alphabet)==0
```

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase` is a string, not a list or dict, so it lacks the `pop` attribute

Comment: Following up @C.Nivs, also even if it was a list or dict, it would be a method, not an attribute.

Comment: @iamvegan I think that borders on semantics, especially when calling a non-existent method raises an `AttributeError`

Answer (score 0):

List and dictionary objects only have `pop`method.You are trying to delete the character in the 0th index of string. Thus you can try this :

```
def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    for x in str1:
        if x in alphabet:
            alphabet = alphabet[1:]
        else:
            pass
    return len(alphabet)==0
```

output

```
print (ispangram("The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog", "s"))

False
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```py
import string 

def check(s):
    """ 
    Return True if string s is Panagram
    """
    alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase
    return set(alphabet) - set(s.lower()) == set([])
```

PS: If you want to see what attributes/methods of an object just use `dir(<object>)`